# How to delete all faces/geometry that isn't visible? Lowering poly count for unity?

Tags: mesh, game-engine, unity, polycount

Ok, Ive looked at [Removing internal geometry before 3D printing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/removing-internal-geometry-before-3d-printing) but am really trying to reduce poly count for export to UNITY especially. Ive decimated and done limited dissolve, but really I still have high poly count owing to internal geometry that is not seen, but augments poly count regardless:

[image]

I just need the "shell" essentially for export to unity. I tried ctrl-alt-shift-M, but Im not sure what this selected, and didn't get much. Select-interior faces does nothing.

How can I get rid of unseen geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Box selection

Go into edit mode <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>.
Switch to solid view mode (toggle <kbd>Z</kbd>).
Switch to face selection <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> > <kbd>F</kbd>.

Box select the faces. <kbd>B</kbd> + drag + <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> confirm
*You have now selected the exterior faces.*

Invert the selection. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
*You have now selected the interior faces.*

Delete the faces <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> > *Faces*.

[image: remove interior faces]