# How do I de-construct a model for a prosthetic?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I found this on a website similar to Thingaverse.

[image]

How do I remove the internals to end up with the outside shell (in this case the finger skin)?

The intent is to create a prosthetic, that looks like a finger, to replace part of a finger.  The finger stub needs to fit inside the prosthetic.

Is there a way to copy the outside layer?  Then the inside could be deleted.

---

The .stl and .blend files can be downloaded from https://temp.foxping.com/

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here, nor where you encounter an issue. Could you edit your post to better explain what you expect to do, what you have tried so far, and where it doesn't get you where you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the gory part?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/removing-internal-geometry-before-3d-printing